# C struct object Stack - function call is not allowed in constant expression (error)

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, visual-studio-2015, stack

I am trying to create a struct object (stack) which consists of:

```
typedef struct node {
    int val;
    struct node * next;
}node_t;

typedef struct {
    node_t * top;
    int max_size;
    int used_size;
} Stack;
```

However, when I try to initialize the object and allocate it some memory space using the function:

```
 Stack * newStack(int max_size) {
    Stack * S = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    S->top = NULL;
    S->max_size = max_size;
    S->used_size = 0;
    return S;
}

Stack * S = newStack(256); //error here
```

I get the error referred to above -

> function call is not allowed in constant expression

I have never come across this type of error before, and I don't know how to tackle it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In C language objects with *static storage duration* can only be initialized with constant expressions.

You are initializing a *global variable* `S`, which is an object with static storage duration. Your expression `newStack(256)` is *not* a constant expression. As the compiler told you already, you are not allowed to call functions in constant expressions. Hence the error. That's all there is to it.

If you want to have a global variable `S`, then the only way to "initialize" it with `newStack(256)` is to do it inside some function at program startup. E.g.

```
Stack * S;

int main()
{ 
  S = newStack(256);
  ...
}
```

Comment: @pm100: Yes, C++ allows this, but the question is about C.

Comment: i was telling the OP that if he changed to c++ he can do what he wants (if thats an option)

Comment: I see, embedded the line in a function and worked. Much obliged!

Comment: Is there any reason for why you can't initialize an object with static storage duration using a non-constant expression?

Answer (score 1):

When in C, Make sure that your call to a function is done inside a function. For instance:-

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int return_something()
{
   return 100;
}

int something = return_something();
```

This would obviously through an error, to resolve the issue, call int_something() from inside some other function frame